# Как из большой вложенности в функции вернуть переменную?

Tags: python, python-3.x

коллеги. Есть такая функция:

```
def check_input():
    while True:
        sanName = input('Enter the name of storage system in 07-06 format: ')
        for row in ws.rows:
            for cell in row:
                if cell.value == sanName:
                    storage_name = str(ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=1).value)
                    storage_rack = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=2).value
                    storage_sn_depo = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=3).value
                    storage_sn_manufactur = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=4).value
                    storage_unit = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=5).value
                    print('Serial number of ' + storage_name + ' is ' + storage_sn_depo + ' and serial number of Netapp ' + storage_sn_manufactur)
                    print(storage_name + ' is installed in the rack ' + storage_rack + ' and unite ' + storage_unit)

                    return storage_name

        else:
            cell.value != sanName
            print('not found this storage, try again')
```

Мне из данной функции требуется переменная storage_name которую я хочу использовать в коде, не совсем понимаю, правильно ли я её вытаскиваю таким способом, можно ли вообще вернуть ещё с помощью Return с такой большой вложенностью циклов.
P.S: Толька большая вложенность из-за того, что все данные берутся из Excel файла

Comment: Ну, да. Так всегда и делают. А почему у вас возникли вдруг сомнения?

Comment: Сомнения из-за большой вложенности while,2х For и if в придачу. + я новичок в python. как мне тогда правильно значение вывести данной переменной ?

Comment: Вложенность не играет роли. В любом языке программирования. `return` - возврат из любого места функции, а не только в конце.

Comment: Тогда как правильно вызвать эту переменную? Не затруднит ли вас написать немного кода?:)

Comment: В смысле "вызвать"? Вызывайте вашу функцию, получайте результат, делайте с ним всё, что пожелаете. `name = check_input();   print(name)`

Comment: Я разобрался, спасибо Вам огромное!